# Word for data/information from medical scanner

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, mathematics, science, medical

I need a word for "information from a scanning as it appears in the image used for diagnostics".

My context is medical (physics).

SPECT and CT are two scanning techniques with different information that is combined into one image:

> "The **SPECT information** is classified into five classes and matched to the CT image"
>
> "In the resulting image the **SPECT information** is delineated more sharply

So, do you know a better word than "information" or "data" in this context?

EDIT: The SPECT information resembles the temperature maps overlayed on a photo in thermal scans (I don't know if this helps)

[image: SPECT/CT]

Edit 2: I realised that my question maybe needs to be a bit more precise; the projection or image is the data in the image matrix. The shape, or contour (or whatever we end up calling it) is the significant part of the image. We sometimes call these hot spots, if the measurements have  high values compared to the background, or cold spots if the background is high, and there are areas with low values.

**Summary**

Here I list the suggestions from answers and comments with informal and formal definitions

- Scan: the process of obtaining an image, also used as a synonym for the image
- Projections: The SPECT raw data (one projection for each scan angle)
- Image: The reconstructed data as a matrix of pixel values
- Measurement: a method of determining quantity, capacity, or dimension.
- Result: the output of a test or the interpretation of data (by e.g. a physician)
- Contour:  the edge or line that defines or bounds a shape or object.
- Topography: The description of the regions of the body or of a body part, especially the regions of a definite and limited area of the surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Dictionary](https://www.google.ca/search?rlz=1CAACAT_enCA736CA736&q=define%20topography&oq=define%20topog&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i67k1j0l3.205231.213577.0.216020.11.8.3.0.0.0.91.601.8.8.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.11.626...35i39k1j0i13k1j0i22i10i30k1.01SirE2QZq4) gives a relevant definition of **topography** as :

> **topography** (*BIOLOGY*, *ANATOMY*)
>
> the distribution of parts or features on the surface of or within an organ or organism.

For example, "In the resulting image the SPECT topography is delineated more sharply".

Comment: I think this is the word I should start to use. I don't think I have seen it used a lot in this context but I like the word.

Answer (score 1):

Though this may be idiomatic, the phrase "test results" (or simply, "results") is widely used to refer to the data output of a test.

> *SPECT **test results** are categorized into five classes and matched to the CT image*
>
> *In the image the SPECT **result** is delineated more sharply...*

*Additional edits to sample sentences were added to eliminate repetition in word use.*

Comment: Results could perhaps work, it is nice and simple. Let's  see if there are other suggestions

Comment: I think I will go with "shape" or "contour". "Result" does not capture that it is image data.

Comment: @stefan: Not clear how technical you want to get, but SPECT is not image data, it is a gamma emission *count*, that represents a density distribution which is then visualized as an image.

Comment: @Yorik it depends on how you define an image; I define an image (loosly) as a visual representation of data in two dimensions

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of suggesting the obvious answer, the image you get out of a scanner is a [scan](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scan).  See the 3rd definition for the noun *scan*: "an image formed by scanning something".

Comment: A scan or an image are synonyms in this context. See my edit 2 for more information of what I am looking for. I think that the suggestions in comments and answer here are all relevant - and maybe I just have to use a less precise word.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest *images* or *projections*, although I think information/data would work as well.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-photon_emission_computed_tomography):

> SPECT imaging is performed by using a gamma camera to acquire multiple 2-D **images** (also called **projections**), from multiple angles. A computer is then used to apply a tomographic reconstruction algorithm to the multiple projections, yielding a 3-D data set.

*Measurements* could work as well ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/measurement)):

> a figure, extent, or amount obtained by measuring

Comment: I realised that my question maybe needs to be a bit more precise; the projection or image is the data in the image matrix. The shape, or contour (or whatever we end up calling it) is the significant part of the image. We sometimes call these hot spots, if there are a lot of counts compared to background, or cold spots if the background is high, and there are areas with low counts